# adding dynamic form fields in rails 7 using stimulus JS framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, stimulusjs

I am using ruby 3.1.2 and rails 7.0.2

this is gem file

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby "3.1.0"

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem "rails", github: "rails/rails", branch: "main"
gem "rails", "~> 7.0.3"

# The original asset pipeline for Rails [https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails]
gem "sprockets-rails"

# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem "pg", "~> 1.1"

# Use the Puma web server [https://github.com/puma/puma]
gem "puma", "~> 5.0"

# Use JavaScript with ESM import maps [https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails]
gem "importmap-rails"

# Hotwire's SPA-like page accelerator [https://turbo.hotwired.dev]
gem "turbo-rails"

# Hotwire's modest JavaScript framework [https://stimulus.hotwired.dev]
gem "stimulus-rails"

# Build JSON APIs with ease [https://github.com/rails/jbuilder]
gem "jbuilder"

# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
gem "redis", "~> 4.0"

# Use Kredis to get higher-level data types in Redis [https://github.com/rails/kredis]
# gem "kredis"

# Use Active Model has_secure_password [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_model_basics.html#securepassword]
# gem "bcrypt", "~> 3.1.7"

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: %i[ mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby ]

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem "bootsnap", require: false

# Use Sass to process CSS
# gem "sassc-rails"

# Use Active Storage variants [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#transforming-images]
# gem "image_processing", "~> 1.2"

group :development, :test do
  # See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#debugging-with-the-debug-gem
  gem "debug", platforms: %i[ mri mingw x64_mingw ]
end

group :development do
  # Use console on exceptions pages [https://github.com/rails/web-console]
  gem "web-console"

  # Add speed badges [https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler]
  # gem "rack-mini-profiler"

  # Speed up commands on slow machines / big apps [https://github.com/rails/spring]
  # gem "spring"
end

group :test do
  # Use system testing [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#system-testing]
  gem "capybara"
  gem "selenium-webdriver"
  gem "webdrivers"
end

gem "requestjs-rails", "~> 0.0.9"
```

create home controller
app/controller/home_controller.rb

```
def add_form
    respond_to do |format|
      format.turbo_stream
        @targtes = params[:target]
    end
end
```

add one route for home controller config/routes.rb file

```
root "home#index"
get "/form_add", to: "home#add_form"
```

create views for views/home
app/views/_form.html.erb

```
<div data-controller="hello">
    <input type="text"/><a href="#" class="remove_class" data-action="click->hello#removeDiv">Remove</a>
</div>
```

app/views/index.html.erb

```
<h1>Home#index</h1>
<div data-controller="hello">
    
    <div data-hello-target="add_form_field" id="results">
        <%= link_to "Add Form", "/", data: { action: "click->hello#showForm" } %>
    </div>
</div>
```

app/views/add_form.turbo_stream.erb

```
<%= turbo_stream.append @targtes do %>
     <%= render partial: "home/form" %>
<% end %>
```

modify stimulus controller inside app/javascript/controllers/hello_controller.js

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"
import {get} from "@rails/request.js"

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = [ "add_form_field" ]
  connect() {
    console.log("hello")
  }
  
  showForm(event){
    event.preventDefault()
   class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'
    
    get(`/form_add?target=${this.add_form_fieldTarget.id}`,{
      responseKind: "turbo-stream"
    })
  }
  
  removeDiv(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    this.element.remove()
  }
}
```

thank you!

Comment: That's all very interesting, but seems like you forgot to ask your question. It's not obvious for other developers what is your problem and what you're trying to achieve